# downloaded file disappears from file manager, but chrome wont re-download (replace), or re-name (create new file)

Tags: chrome-for-android, lg, 7.1-nougat

Android 7.1 on LG phone
"stock" chrome
I download a movie,
its a really long filename,
and the file didn't show up in downloads

so few days later I stumble upon same movie,
try to download, and chrome says file already exists

I check "downloads" in "file manager" but there is nothing there
I choose replace file option, file is not replace
I choose create new file option, and a file shows up in downloads in file manager
but as soon as I close file manager, the file is gone

so i try it again, but this time it wont rename file
it also wont replace file (pretends its downloading, then says already downloaded, but no file)

So I added a .nomedia to the directory cause I don't want this file randomly popping up ;)

how do I reveal this file? get rid of it?
It doesn't show up when I connect to laptop either

**update:** file is like 352 characters, should I post the url?

> wwwwwwwww.www_ww+wwwwww+wwwwwwwwwww+wwwww+wwwwwww+wwwwwww+www+www+wwwww+ww+wwwwwwww+ww+www+w+wwww+www+www+wwwww+w+ww+www+www+wwww+wwwwwwwwww+www+wwww+wwwwww+wwww+www+ww+wwww+wwwwwwww+wwwwww+wwwww+wwww+www+wwwww+www+ww+wwwwww+wwwwwwwwww+wwww+www+wwwww+ww+wwwww+www+wwwwwww+ww+ww+w+wwwww+ww+wwwww+www+wwwwww+www+www+wwww+www+www+wwww+wwwwwwwwww_240p.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following

- Storage type

> Are you sure your file is on phones internal storage and not on a micro sdcard. If it’s on a micro sdcard then connect it with you PC and execute the following on terminal `cd the/sdcard/Downloads` then remove the file `rm long-file-name.mp4` (after a few characters hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it’ll type it for you.) Or format your sdcard (but first copy the files/folders you care about, do not copy downloads folder)

- Basic hidden files

> Make sure in your file explorer “show hidden files” option is enabled, use a 3rd party file explorer.

- Use terminal

> Connect your phone with PC and in terminal `cd to/the/phone/storage/Downloads` then remove the file `rm long-file-name.mp4` (after a few characters hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it’ll type it for you.)

- If you’re root user

> Try to find the file using root explorer, rename the file name to something simple or delete it.

- Wipe your storage

> Copy the files/folder you care about manually (do not copy downloads folder) then wipe the internal storage.